# No option for adding online packages in VS 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to install a few online or external packages into my project using nuget in Visual Studio 2017. I tried the package console and it fails. The problem seems to be that the only package source I have available as an option is "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline". There is no "All" option in the package source drop down at the top of the package console, which I believe I need to see if I am trying to add online packages. I have searched all over the place for what might be a simple answer, but all answers seem to deal with other related matters and not specifically this one. Maybe I didn't type the correct phrase to yield results, but I tried and couldn't find them. What am I missing? A setting? Not the correct license? Thanks.

PM> install-package jquery
install-package : Unable to find package 'jquery'
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package jquery
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Visual Studio Community can work with packages without issues. If you only see `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline` it means that somehow the source were lost or unselected. Go to `NuGet Package Manager` settings and check the `Package Sources`. You can get there either through `Tools > Options` or `NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings`. Do you see the `nuget.org` source there? If not you need to add it. Its URL is `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Comment: normally the nuget.org source is listed in `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config`, if you don't see it there, you did something to delete and should add it back. If it is there, then you have another nuget.config that either uses `<clear />` or explicitly removes the nuget.org source. You should check every directory from your csproj or sln file, up to the root directory for `nuget.config` and `.nuget\nuget.config`.

Comment: both comments were helpful and correct. Thank you. First comment should be added as an answer because it worked. I saw the option for adding a source before and tried it but I didn't know the correct url to try. Don't know why it wasn't there by default but now it works. Thank you

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, please add an answer with your solution, since it solved Bobh's issue, that will also help others to easier search this useful information, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to manage NuGet package manager, click to setting gear button.
Then add new package source:

```
Name: nuget.org
URL: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```